# Elementary (CFSG-avoiding) proof that the order of a group of composite order is bounded by the square of the order of its largest proper subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, simple-groups

It seems that the following is true.  For a finite group $G,$ define $u(G)$ to be the largest order of a proper subgroup of $G$.  Then $\left|G\right|\leq u(G)^2$ provided that the order of $G$ is composite. However, my argument relies on the [classification of finite simple groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_simple_groups) in that I need to know that $\left|G\right| < u(G)^2$, when $G$ is non-abelian simple, and I did this by checking the maximal subgroups of groups on the [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_finite_simple_groups). (The simple case is actually almost all of the work.)  This feels a bit like driving a thumb tack with a sledgehammer, especially since the remainder of the argument is completely elementary. Given how neatly the bound worked out (and assuming that this is indeed correct), it seems like the sort of thing that must have been known for a very long time, and probably has a fairly simple proof that I've been unable to discover for myself.

**Question.**  Can this be proved by more elementary means (that is, without resorting to the classification of finite simple groups)?

Comment: Brauer proved that for a finite nonabelian simple group $G$ there is an involution $x$ with $|G| < |C_G(x)^3|$, but that's weaker than what you are looking for.

Comment: @DerekHolt I see that they actually mention that this square bound is true for soluble groups in the first paragraph of the paper.  So perhaps my expectation that there is a simple argument for the general result that goes back to earlier than that is unwarranted.